# How do you use wget to install files that change urls

Tags: java, minecraft, wget

I run a Minecraft server, but when I am trying to make it so every time the server starts, it would look for updates for plugins etc.

```
#!/bin/sh

wget -O EssentialsX.jar -P ~/Desktop/BlizzardMC/plugins https://ci.ender.zone/job/EssentialsX/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/jars/EssentialsX-2.19.0-dev+162-780aade.jar
```

This link will only get the current build. Once they update the plugin, the link will change. Now the link is useless. Is there a way to get the latest build or link change or something? Thanks

Comment: See if the developers have a static link for the current version. Otherwise you might use the `-r` option of `wget` to download an entire directory recursively.  In both cases, consider the possibility that your plan could backfire and cause problems with your software if an incorrect or incompatible version replaces a working one.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll try that out